# Problem in uploded website?

Tags: php, html, css, javascript

I built a static web site in urdu font via uni code, it is not working well, it is only open in IE8, firefox, not in safari and not in  Google Chrome,
In IE8, firefox not supporting to Font, it is working well at localhost.
address is: http://jamia-siddiquia .org/

**WARNING: linked site is blocked by google due to supposed malware distribution **

Comment: It opens fine in Opera. You should try to make the site validate though - this is the first step to browser compatibility. http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: First, get rid of the malware your site is distributing (it got blocked by google). Then someone may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://validator.w3.org/

and http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Remove any Malware suspicious links files. If the font isn't supported use a different font or Sifr

Comment: me validate it, but same problem

Comment: Error: Page cannot be displayed. Please contact service provider for more details. (3) This message displayed at Firefox.

Comment: Error: Page cannot be displayed. Please contact service provider for more details. (2) at Safari.

Comment: Strip your page of any links to external webpage

Comment: No there is no link with external webpage.